# AngularJS url from email link with random ID

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a public url with a unique ID appended to it in angular. The link is sent via email and when clicked it opens up `www.my-domain.com/SharedDocument/unique-id-appended`.

The `$routeParams.id` approach doesn't seem to work in this case since the app is not running on the tab that will open when the link is clicked.

I tried building a dynamic url and making it part of the routes...

```
var dynamicSharedUrl = "/SharedDocument/" + window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
// this gives the ID


// then i make dynamicSharedUrl a path    
.when(dynamicSharedUrl , {
        templateUrl: "views/sharedDoc.html",
        controller: "SharedDocCtrl"
})
```

It doesn't seem to recognize the url, get a 404.

Is there a way of creating AngularJS url with a random ID appended?

Comment: Does this code belongs to angular.config? otherwise it won't work..

Comment: add with `#` if you haven't add with html5mode

Comment: PLease clarify what you mean with 'since the app is not running on the tab that will open when the link is clicked.'

Comment: @pankajparkar yes the code is belongs to angulat.config.

Comment: @Anzeo when the link is clicke on email it will open a new tab.

Comment: I would say that SharedDocument is not defined in your server-side router, therefore server throws 404. If this is the case, then it has nothing to do with Angular

Comment: @DavidVotrubec  Yes you might be right that is one of disadvantage of while using html5mode it will hit server if route didn't register in $routeProvider

Comment: why it matters if the link open in the same tab, other tab, other window or even other browser? it has nothing to do.

Comment: @DavidVotrubec SharedDocument is defined on server-side router, the 404 is a result of  `.otherwise({
          redirectTo: "/404"
      })` in angular..

Comment: @AvraamMavridis i was elaborating on what i think would give detail to the matter at hand, if it doesnt help then edit the question and help phrase it correctly

Comment: why you dont have a route like `/SharedDocument/:unique_id` and then read the `unique_id` from the `route.params` ?